# How can I display an arraylist object in a tabular format using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

```html
<table border="1" style="width: 95%; border-collapse: collapse;">
    
  <tr>
    <td class="headercol"><b>INST_ID</b></td>
    <td class="headercol"><b>SID</b></td>
    <td class="headercol"><b>SERIAL</b></td>
    <td class="headercol"><b>SPID</b></td>
    <td class="headercol"><b>USERNAME</b></td>
    <td class="headercol"><b>OSUSER</b></td>
    <td class="headercol"><b>STATUS</b></td>
    <td class="headercol"><b>MODULE</b></td>
    <td class="headercol"><b>MACHINE</b></td>
    <td class="headercol"><b>SQL_HASH_VALUE</b></td>
    <td class="headercol"><b>LOGON_TIME</b></td>
    <td class="headercol"><b>IDLE_MINS</b></td>
  </tr>
  <s:iterator value="sessionDetailsBean">
    <tr>
      <td class="rowcol"><s:property value="INST_ID" /></td>
      <td class="rowcol"><s:property value="SID" /></td>
      <td class="rowcol"><s:property value="SERIAL" /></td>
      <td class="rowcol"><s:property value="SPID" /></td>
      <td class="rowcol"><s:property value="USERNAME" /></td>
      <td class="rowcol"><s:property value="OSUSER" /></td>
      <td class="rowcol"><s:property value="STATUS" /></td>
      <td class="rowcol"><s:property value="MODULE" /></td>
      <td class="rowcol"><s:property value="MACHINE" /></td>
      <td class="rowcol"><s:property value="SQL_HASH_VALUE" /></td>
      <td class="rowcol"><s:property value="LOGON" /></td>
      <td class="rowcol"><s:property value="IDLE_MINS" /></td>
    </tr>
  </s:iterator>
  
</table>
```

I am fetching data from database and then storing it in an arraylist. I want to display the arraylist object in a jsp page. `sessionDetailsBean` is the arraylist where I am storing the values fetched from database. I want to convert it into angularjs. How do I do this?

Comment: OK, but where's the code?

Comment: And what do ArrayLists and JSP pages have to do with AngularJS? AngularJS apps are supposed to get their data from REST services returning JSON structures.

Comment: @JBNizet so angularjs reads only json data?? can we not use angularjs to iterate through an arraylist?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have arraylists. It's executed in the browser. The ArrayList only exists on the server.

Comment: AngularJS only works on the client-side. The kinds of things you do in a JSP page happen on the server. All the JSP rendering will have already taken place by the time your AngularJS code runs; any Java objects (such as ArrayList) will not be available to your AngularJS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular only works on the client-side. The kinds of things you do in a JSP page happen on the server. All the JSP rendering will have already taken place by the time your Angular code runs; any Java objects (such as ArrayList) will not be available to your Angular code.

Angular can handle any kind of data format that JavaScript can handle, but JSON is often the easiest to work with.  You could create a web service in Java that converts your ArrayList to JSON (this is easily done using a serialization library). Exactly how to create this web service depends on your environment--are you already using a web [framework](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/)? Then you probably have a JSON serlization library available to you. Your Angular code can then make an AJAX request to retrieve this data and process it however you like.  If you're planning to display the data in a table, I suggest using the Angular [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive.

Comment: Yeah ng-repeat is what I use for tables in angular.